# Странная ошибка не даёт выйти из программы

Tags: ncurses, gcc, c++

Что это значит?

```
*** glibc detected *** ./proga: corrupted double-linked list: 0x093d4108 ***
```

Вылезает это и никак не закрывается. Программу приходится завершать с помощью с помощью: "kill -9". Ctr-C не помогает. Не до, не после.

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит так: «У меня в программе где-то ошибка. Скажите, где именно.» Мы не телепаты, так что вам придётся сначала поработать самостоятельно. Найдите проблемное место в программе: выкидывайте из программы **всё**, что можно, до тех пор, пока проблема не исчезнет. В этот момент с хорошей вероятностью вам станет очевидно, в чём проблема. Если нет, постите сюда **код**.

Телепаты уехали отдыхать, до осени не ждите.

Answer (score 2):

Это известная ошибка. Но она слишком общая. Суть в том, что Вы пытаетесь дважды удалить один и тот же объект. Или пытаетесь удалить (то есть просто вызвать деструктор) для объекта, который должен быть удален glibc'ом.

Для начала установите valgrind, который есть практически в любом дистрибутиве линукс. Запустите с под него программу

```
valgrind -v ./имя_бинарника
```

посмотрите на вывод, возможно, его нужно будет перенаправить в файл. Скорее всего, Вы найдете виновника.

NB: желательно компилировать в дебажном режиме. Если не знаете что это, то просто в опции компиляции добавьте `-ggdb` и уберите `-O1`( или подобное `-O2 -O3 -Os`).

на почитать:

- [Что такое valgrind и зачем он нужен](http://alexott.net/ru/writings/prog-checking/Valgrind.html)
- [Использование Valgrind для поиска утечек и недопустимого использования памяти](http://cppstudio.com/uchebniki/otladka-programm/ispolzovanie-valgrind-dlya-poiska-utechek-i-nedopustimogo-ispolzovaniya-pamyati/)